# Xpath Child node query

Tags: html, xpath

```
<tr>
  <td><span style="white-space:nowrap">Aug 29, 2016 06:05</span></td>
  <td><a class="A" title="B" href="C">
  <td>....
   ....

</tr>
```

I have many < td> elements wrapped in < tr> elements among the html I want to access every single text within the first < td> element in its < tr> wrap and 
every single href for the second < td> element.

Should probably use 2 different queries for each.

```
char = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/@href')
```

this is what I came up with for the href query but wouldn't do the work for me.

**Update**

thanks to help from lauda I got in the right track

This is what worked out for me

```
first = tree.xpath('//tr/td/span/text()')
second = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/@href')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is not directly in the `td`, for the first you could use something like:

```
//tr/td/span
```

for the second:

```
//tr/td/a
```

or if you want the href and not the element then:

```
//tr/td/a/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot that lead me to the right direction
   date = tree.xpath('//tr/td/span/text()')
   hrefs = tree.xpath('//tr/td[2]/a/@href')